# Salesforce Web-to-Lead Form in Squarespace

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to insert a Web-to-Lead Form from Salesforce into a Code block of a Squarespace page. This is a slightly formatted version with tables, but even if I take the pure Web-to-Lead form it just doesn't create a Lead in the CRM.

The form itself submits and goes to the `retURL`, and this happens despite making the fields required and filling all of the fields. In Squarespace I've put the `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` in the Code of the Settings.

Edit: I can't find any advice for how to use this with Squarespace except to use Zapier, which I now see has a free tier. This seems to work, but not ideally. I would be interested to see if there are other solutions, but Zapier seems to be the best one I can find.

```html
<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

<input type=hidden name="oid" value="OID">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="WEBSITE URL">
    
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><label for="salutation">Salutation*: </label></td>
<td><select  id="salutation" name="salutation" required="true"><option value="">--None--</option>
  <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
<option value="Prof.">Prof.</option>
<option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
<option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
<option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
<option value="Mx.">Mx.</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="first_name">First Name*: </label></td>
<td><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Mandatory" required="true"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="last_name">Surname*: </label></td>
<td><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Mandatory" required="true"/></td>
</tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><label for="phone">Phone*</label></td>
    <td><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" required="true"/></td>
    
  </tr>
  
<tr>
<td><label for="email">E-Mail*: </label></td>
<td><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Mandatory" required="true"/></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td><label for="company">Company*: </label></td>
<td><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Mandatory" required="true"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="street">Street, Housenumber *: </label></td>
<td><textarea name="street" placeholder="Mandatory" required="true"></textarea></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td><label for="zip">ZIP Code*: </label></td>
<td><input  id="zip" maxlength="20" name="zip" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Mandatory" required="true"/></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td><label for="city">City*: </label></td>
<td><input  id="city" maxlength="40" name="city" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Mandatory" required="true"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> <label for="state">State/Province*</label></td>
  <td><input  id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" required="true"/></td>
</tr>
  
    <tr>
<td><label for="country_code">Country*: </label></td>
      <td><select  id="country_code" name="country" required="true"/>
<option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
        <option value="NA">Namibia</option></td>
</tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Contact Type:</td>
      <td><select  id="ID" name="ID" title="Contact Type" required="true">
      <option value="CONTACT TYPE">CONTACT TYPE</option>
</select>
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
    
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" checked required="true"> Yes, I agree to the processing of my data.*
   </div>
    <div>
  <input type="checkbox" > Yes, I have read the <u><a href="URL/data-privacy" target="_blank">data protection declaration</a></u> and agree.*
   </div>

  <input id="lead_source" name="lead_source" type="hidden" value="LEAD SOURCE">
<br>
<input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: That `<input type=hidden name="oid" value="OID">` - in the final html is it really "OID" or do you have some variable substitution that populates it with `00D...`?

Comment: @eyescream Thanks for your comment, I don't have a variable substitution. I ended up finding a solution with a third-party service called Zapier, which is not quite ideal but seems to be the only working solution with Squarespace that I can find. Would still be interested in other answers to this problem them.

Comment: Here is the step-by-step guide for the Salesforce web to lead feature. You can also find some other methods to create dynamic forms in salesforce.

https://arrify.com/salesforce-form-guide